# How to send keys to "other pane"?

Tags: tmux

Reading the [tmux man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1), I would think that the command to send characters from one pane to the other in a two-pane setup would be the following:

```
tmux send-keys -t + "ls -l"
```

But it just sends to the same pane I'm currently in. However, if I do the following:

```
tmux send-keys -t %1 "ls -l"
```

where %0 is my current pane and %1 is the "other" pane, then it does work properly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` can be used to specify either the “next window” or the “next pane”. A bare `+` is always interpreted as “next window” due to the way the parsing is done.

To force the “next pane” interpretation use `.+` (FULL STOP followed by PLUS SIGN):

```
tmux send-keys -t .+ 'ls -l'
```